# Should I consider SpriteKit for a non-game iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am contemplating the possibility of using Sprite Kit for a non-game app as I like the idea of having all these cool animations, motions, particle effects etc. available for my app. It would look really cool!

Could someone tell me why this is not a good idea (if that is so)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. Sprite Kit was obviously created with games in mind, but there is no reason you can't use it for regular applications that have similar needs.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with @Stefan Arentz, but you should also check this out:

[Creating Simple Animations with Facebook’s Pop Framework](http://www.appcoda.com/facebook-pop-framework-intro/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the pointer! this is indeed quite interesting. Do you know if the framework forces Facebook integration, data sharing or something like that?

Comment: No it doesn't.  It's just something that they happened to develop separately, that they broke out into a separate set of re-useable classes.